# access selected value of QcomboBox

Tags: qt, qcombobox, getdate

I set a QcomboBox in gui widget and ,I add item

```
for(int i = 1; i < 31; i++)
        {
            ui->combo->addItem(QString::number(i));
        }
```

and in QComboBox slot I want to get selected value by

```
int index =ui->combo->itemData( ui->combo->currentText());
```

but have error :`316: error: no matching function for call to 'QComboBox::itemData(QString)'`

if I use `currentIndex` instead of `currentText` return 0 when print it;
addItem get Qstring ,

```
void QComboBox::addItem(const QString & text, const QVariant & userData = QVariant())
```

and ItemData work with currentIndex,

I use insertItem and it has sae error ,so how can set value or text and get slected value??

Comment: @thuga it's incorrect type I edited

Comment: Why don't you juse use `int index = ui->combo->currentIndex();`? In the code you've posted you never set any data to your combo box, that is why `itemData` returns 0. Or if you want to get the current text just use `QString selected_text = ui->combo->currentText();`.

Comment: @thuga if I use this  `index = ui->combo->currentIndex();` when I run the program get currentindex without select ,for example if I set 1 to 31 when run without select currentindex is 1

Comment: @thuga I set data by this way `ui->combo->addItem(QString::number(i));` and I try insertItem() , they have return 0,so how can set data??

Comment: That is not the same as `QComboBox::setItemData`. Anyway the problem is not there. `currentIndex`/`currentText` should work. Where do you even check for the `currentIndex`/`currentText`? Have you connected a slot to some signal of your combo box?

Comment: @thuga I set comboBox in gui and go to  slot of comboBox,in the slot after `index=  ui->setfreq->itemData(ui->setfreq->currentIndex()).toInt();` I set
 `qDebug() << "current index:"<<index;` printout 0.

Comment: Which slot? And again, as I stated before, using `itemData` like that will not give you any valid data. Use `index = ui->setfreq->currentIndex` and see what that returns. Check my answer for a working example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the current index like this:

```
int index = ui->combo->currentIndex();
```

Or if you want the text:

```
QString text = ui->combo->currentText();
```

In the code you've posted you never set any data with the `Qt::UserRole` to your combobox, that is why `itemData` returns 0. If you want to use `itemData` you have to set the role to `Qt::DisplayRole`:

```
ui->combo->itemData(index, Qt::DisplayRole)
```

But there is no reason to do this when you have nice functions that return the selected index/text provided by the `QComboBox` class. Here is a working example:

```
#ifndef MYWIDGET_H
#define MYWIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QLayout>
#include <QComboBox>
#include <QDebug>

class MyWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyWidget(QWidget *parent = 0) : QWidget(parent)
    {
        setLayout(new QVBoxLayout);
        comboBox = new QComboBox;
        for(int i = 1; i < 31; i++)
            comboBox->addItem(QString::number(i));
        connect(comboBox, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)), this, SLOT(cbIndexChanged()));    
        layout()->addWidget(comboBox);
    }

public slots:
    void cbIndexChanged()
    {
        int index = comboBox->currentIndex();
        QString text = comboBox->currentText();

        qDebug() << index << text << comboBox->itemData(index, Qt::DisplayRole);
    }

private:
    QComboBox *comboBox;
};

#endif // MYWIDGET_H
```

Comment: tnx , and for example when i select 10 , index printout 9 and text printout 10??

Comment: @g1331 That is expected. `currentIndex` returns the current index. And usually indexes start from 0. If you have an array or a container, the first item is in the index 0.

Comment: tank you it's very helpful.